# How do I get Google Chrome extension to share data with an OSX app similar to 1password

Tags: swift, macos, google-chrome-extension

I am looking at the features of 1password app which allows us to save a password and access the same data via its mac osx app.

If I was to create an chrome extension for my OSX app - how could it share data with a chrome extension and the Mac App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two broad possibilities:

- [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). That's the more secure mechanism, but has only-one-way-to-use-it that essentially means you'll need some "proxy" application that Chrome can start, and that can communicate with your application - it cannot connect to an already-running process.
- Local Web(Socket) server. Your native application can open a local port and the extension would try to connect to it and talk this way. Makes it hard to authenticate parties: your extension and your app has no warranties they are not talking to something hostile. Include your own authentication.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29591150/934239).

FWIW, 1password uses a local WebSocket port.